# how to dynamically load configuraiton file in spring

Tags: java, spring

In a running spring app, could it monitor a folder under which I could put more configuration file in which more beans are defined? I don't want to stop the app, but want the ability to add load more beans, so I am thinking of create a folder, and then put bean definitions into that folder, and let spring to pick it up and initialize the beans. I am wondering whether it is doable or not

Comment: Why do you even want to do that? In most cases changing bean definitions requires deployments as well (due to code changes)...

Comment: Not change bean definition, but to add more more definition. I just want to add a jar file, let spring pick it up, and then let it pick up a configuration pointing to the new bean defined in the jar file. Is it possible?

Comment: @DanielWu There is a class 'AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext' in Spring and it has a method 'loadBeanDefinitions' so maybe it would be a good way to check it out. You could enforce 'refresh()' on the context and then 'loadBeanDefinitions' would get called... but it is a long shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two things

1. A file watcher to watch for file system changes - JDK7 provides a [way](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes) to do this.
2. Refresh the application context - You can use the `refresh` method of one of the `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext` class: it won't refresh your previously instantiated beans, but next call on context will return refreshed beans.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a properties file and load it dynamically

refer below code which i have used in my project:

```
private static Properties beanProps = new Properties();
beanFactoryFileProps.load(AppContext.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("configFile.properties"));
            Collection props = beanProps.values();
            String[] configFiles = null;
            if (!Utils.isEmpty(props)) {
                Object[] config = props.toArray();
                configFiles = new String[config.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
                    configFiles[i] = (String) config[i];
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                configFiles=new String[] {"dispatcher-servlet.xml"};
            }
```

properties file as below

```
file1=dispatcher-servlet.xml
file2=ApplicationContext.xml
file2=QuartzSchedulerContext.xml
```